# How to fix 'Failed to Update dependency information of the project. Please restore the project and try again'

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core-2.0, scaffolding

I'm writing a new web API using .net core 2.2 and I connected an existing database using entity framework. but I keep getting an error saying above when I try to add a controller to the existing model using Scaffold new item.
here are the commands I used

```
Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools
Install-Package Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design
```

Scaffold-DbContext to reverse engineer and create the EF model based on my existing database.

but keeps getting below error

"There was an error running the selected code generator: ' Failed to update dependency information for the project. Please restore the project and try again.'

I tried everything I could think of and I even gets the same error when I tries to add an empty controller also

Comment: What is your vs version? Do you use with EF or EF Core? Do you have any error while rebuild this project? Are these references installed?

Comment: @TaoZhou, I'm using VS 2017 Community version.
I used the above mentioned libraries. Therefore its EF core and no it  gets build successfully

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was due to a mismatch between .netCore version and EntityFrameworkCore version.

Edit
I uninstalled the EFCore and installed a parallel versiion for .net core

Ex 
.netCore 2.0.9
EFCore 2.2.4

Comment: please elaborate on how what you did exactly to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I met this issue and found nothing wrong in my project.

After deleting the `bin` and `obj` folder, this issue is gone.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same error
then i uninstalled all packages and reinstall them again throught nuget
i don't no why but it worked for me